# Unable to access value from dict to variable and print it

Tags: python, scripting

I am not able to figure out why this simple piece of code is not running.

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Without the print statement, the code runs fine and prints correctly, but when I use the print statement: `print ( linebits['core_time'] )` it throws the error.

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import string
import sys
import re

log = open("/tmp/log1", "r")

reg_time = re.compile('(time=)(?P<core_time>[1-9]+.\d..)')

def parse_line(arg):
    regMatch = reg_time.search(arg)
    if regMatch:
        linebits = regMatch.groupdict()
        pp = float( linebits['core_time'] )
        print pp

for line in log:
    parse_line(line)
```

Comment: I am using Python2.6

Comment: I get no `SyntaxError` from your code after fixing the indentation. Also, you should make regular expression strings raw and I think the following is what is needed here: `re.compile(r'(time=)(?P<core_time>[1-9]+\.\d+)')`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not mixing spaces and tabs in your editor - your indentation inside parse_line looks suspect.

If your editor supports it, set it to use 4 spaces when you hit tab.  If it doesn't then rather avoid using tab for indentation altogether.

Your code runs fine.  However I'd suggest the following improvements:

1. Mark regex strings as raw by prefixing your strings with r - that'll preserve any escape characters that are common in regex strings
2. Use underscores, not camel-case, in variable names
3. Avoid white-space inside brackets - ie after and before ( and )
4. Use two blank lines before every functions declaration

Here's the PEP-8 compliant version of your code with the suggestions above:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

log = open("/tmp/log1", "r")


reg_time = re.compile(r'(time=)(?P<core_time>[1-9]+.\d..)')


def parse_line(arg):
    reg_match = reg_time.search(arg)
    if reg_match:
        linebits = reg_match.groupdict()
        pp = float(linebits['core_time'])
        print pp

for line in log:
    parse_line(line)
```

Comment: Thanks @martineau  . Never expected indentation.